# How I calculate how much growth the balance

Tags: laravel

How I calculate how much growth the balance?
For Example bellow

1. Main balance is 5000
2. Profit 750

How I get how much grow 750 as percentage from 5000?

Answer (score 0):

You would calculate the percentage like this:

```js
750 * 100 / 5000    // 15%
```

So the formula is:

```js
profit * 100 / balance
```

However this is not a question about code but rather about maths so it does not really belong on stack overflow.